# Displaying URL taxonomy term as page title

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

How can I display a taxonomy term in the url [example.com/taxonomy/% (% being the term)] of a page as title for that page - no view involved?

I assume it will require a block with some PHP or some hacking of a template.

In either case, what's the PHP and where do I put it?

I use D7 and Bartik.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Taxonomy Title](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_title) is the only module that let's you control that title individually for **every term**. (You can also override the title generally by using a **view** or a **pannel**.) An additional "Taxonomy Term Page - heading" field wil appear on the taxonomy term edit form, allowing administrators to configure a specific heading for each term page.

> The taxonomy title module also provides tokens which can be used in
>   conjunction with the [Page title](https://drupal.org/project/page_title) and [Meta tags](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) modules.
>
> This module was designed to update the heading tag at the top of the
>   taxonomy term page. The contents of this H1 (or sometimes H2) tag are
>   *extremely* important for ***SEO (Search Engine Optimization)***. People interested in SEO may prefer to add more user-friendly, keyword-rich,
>   and descriptive words to this heading element.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: override default taxonomy term display callback and do whatever you want with $term object. For ex., how do I usually do this with taxonomy_override module: 1. Define callback:

```
function MODULENAME_taxonomy_override_define_callback() {
  return array('my_term_display_callback' => 'Display Callback');
}
```

and callback itself:

```
function my_term_display_callback($term) {

  //Title display. DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
  drupal_set_title($term->name);
  //or
  drupal_set_title($term->tid);
  //or
  drupal_set_title($term->vid);
  //or
  drupal_set_title($term->tid . ' -> ' . $term->name);
  //...


  // Build breadcrumb based on the hierarchy of the term.
  $current = (object) array(
    'tid' => $term->tid,
  );

  $breadcrumb = array();
  while ($parents = taxonomy_get_parents($current->tid)) {
    $current = array_shift($parents);
    $breadcrumb[] = l($current->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $current->tid);
  }

  $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), NULL);
  $breadcrumb = array_reverse($breadcrumb);
  $breadcrumb[] = '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
  drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);

  // Set the term path as the canonical URL to prevent duplicate content.
  $uri = entity_uri('taxonomy_term', $term);
  drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => url($uri['path'], $uri['options'])), TRUE);
  // Set the non-aliased path as a default shortlink.
  drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'shortlink', 'href' => url($uri['path'], array_merge($uri['options'], array('alias' => TRUE)))), TRUE);
  // usual part of term ends



  // DISPLAY.. DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
  if(someKindOfCheck) {
    return views_embed_view('viewName', 'blockOrPage');
  }
  elseif(anotherCheck) {
    return views_embed_view('viewName', 'blockOrPageWitchArgument', $term->tid);
  }
  else {
    return render(someRenderArray);
  }
}
```